# Add a reverse proxy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, reverse-proxy

I have a rails app running on heroku at, e.g myapp.herokuapp.com.

Now I want to reverse proxy from `myapp.heroku.com/proxy/` to `somewhereelse.com/` (i.e: `myapp.heroku.com/proxy/stuff` is reverse proxifed to `somewhereelse.com/stuff`) 
Is that possible on Heroku? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone coming to this question through a search, this can be done.

Check out https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack to vendor nginx into your heroku instance. This will place nginx in front of your rails app, and allow you to reverse proxy requests on this domain, having your heroku app configured as apex and allowing somewhereelse.com/stuff go elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have access to frontend routing infrastructure so its not possible to do add something like nginx location based reverse proxying or apache's modproxy. From my understanding too you can only bind to one port (the $PORT) within the dyno so its not possible to shadow your Rails app with your own vendored version of nginx (unless it is possible to communicate over a non TCP/IP socket between nginx and your rack/rails app, if this is the case then perhaps you can get rack to listen to /tmp/mysocket.git and nginx to reverse proxy on this, this could be a no starter though, Im just throwing out ideas).

Which means the only probable option if you have to handle this yourself in your rails app, I have only a tiny tiny bit of rails/ruby experience, but if no proxy functionality exists in rails then you perhaps you can explicitly accept the route and then use a http client to invoke the other parts.