# Is anyone providing their own routing mesh with a reverse proxy back to Heroku as a backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, reverse-proxy, unicorn

I'm interested in having a Heroku backend i.e. application server, database server, workers, add ons, etc.

I would like to provide my own routing mesh though, and reverse proxy with Nginx and unicorn server for a Rails app.

Does this seem possible before I give it a shot. I would assume that I could just provide my apps Heroku domain in the upstream directive?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of stuff will you do with nginx?  Tying together multiple apps under one subdomain?  Microcaching?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not provide a way to configure this in their reverse proxy, but you can run your own, e.g. with [nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27788633/2866660)).