# Cannot GET /post Reactjs and nodejs application

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I know this question was asked a lot of times, but I couldn't get any solution for it,

I am facing a very common issue while deploying my reactjs and nodes application on Heroku with MySQL database.

the project is working well until I go/navigate between pages and refresh the page it will show this message. Cannot GET /post/70 for example, if I go to this URL.

```
here is the demo
```

https://stackrefugee.herokuapp.com/post/97

I did a lot of research, I found a solution for that. the solution that I found was this, to use this in the server-side, with build folder

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build",  
   "index.html"));
});
```

So like this, it will work perfectly, but it doesn't load the data from the database.
when I tried this one  `app.get("/html/*", (req, res)` so like this, it is loading the data and everything is working perfectly except the **URL** nad navigating between pages, but then this is what I am facing Cannot GET /post/70

and this is my project structure.

I have a client-side and a server-side, so on the client-side, I did `npm run build` and cut out the entire build folder from the client-side put it into the server-side. and then deployed the application on the Heroku.

I appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: You said you made some research and you found the solution for the  "GET /post/70". What did you search ? What’s the problem causing this error ?

Comment: yep, the solution i found was this.

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build",  
   "index.html"));
});

but like this, it doesn't load the data from the database. and what i did it load the data was this, i get app.get("/Html*", (req, res) => {...}) so i used HTML after slash it worked, but no it causing another error cannot get.

Comment: What the ressources on /post/70 ? Is this a route of your express server ? Can you provide the code related to this route, pls ?

Comment: Well yeah, post/70 is a router in front-end, 

    <Route path="/post/:id" exact>
              <Post />
            </Route>

Comment: I think that instead of making your server static, you need to make a reverse proxy so that your backend and your frontend are on the same adress. You can check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356058/add-a-reverse-proxy-to-heroku) Sorry I don’t have time to make a full and clear answer)

Comment: thanks a lot, but if you have time anytime you can answer here so I will see it later. thanks again.